# How to convert double values from df to year values/strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have a dataframe with year values like: 2014.0, 2013.0... as float values. I would need to convert these values to year format, like 2014, 2013... I tried converting them to string, but I get "2014.0", "2013.0"...
How could I convert them to year, not double or strings?
This is what I tried for string conversion:

```
df['year']=df['year'].astype(str)
```

And then:

```
df['year']= pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y')
```

But this gave me results like: 1640995200000 and so on. How could I convert the doubles to reasonable year format?

Comment: If remove `df['year']=df['year'].astype(str)` same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do this !!works!!

```
df['year']=df['year'].astype(int)
```

output:

```
2004
2005
2017
```

converting to str does this 2014.0 => "2014.0" so that wont help you and converting using datetime will add whole date. so if you need only that particular year do this int remains datatype of that column not datetime objects

Comment: Thanks! Is it something I could do like df['year'][0].year, to get only the year? (But for the entire df column)

Comment: .year is not required just df['year'][0] will return you year

Comment: for whole column just use df['year']